# Creating register method for mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

Made a small front end for the register page, not sure how to actually register users in the mongodb. CRUD methods are written, the question is how to take parameters from the view's text boxes and parse it all the way to the data layer? This is my button for the submit register form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input ="Submit" id="Padding" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-primary" />
    <a href="Home">or cancel</a>
</div>
```

User controller is empty for now. Not sure if in MVC I can use onClick="" method for the button, probably not, because there is no code behind file. At first I thought that somehow I should be able to call the Padding.Click() or whatever method, but it doesn't seem to be a right way.

Comment: Yes in MVC you can use `onCick=""`, @Kelb56 like this `<input type="Submit" id="Padding" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="" />`

Comment: using a javascript call you can pass the parameters to you controller's action to execute what you want to do

Answer (score 2):

Use strongly typed data binding for posting data from view to controller like:

**POCO**

```
 public class RegisterUser
 {
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

**Register.cstml**

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<h4>Create a new account.</h4>
<hr />
<div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.All" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Email" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Password" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller's Action method**

```
    public IActionResult Register(RegisterUser model)
    {
            //send data to data layer and then can be inserted into mongodb or may be in some other databases
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve. But first let's correct your html/

```
<input ="Submit" id="Padding" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

should be

```
<input type="Submit" id="Padding" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

You are missing the type attribute in your button. Now you html is correct.

Next: You can use onclick() on your button as below:

```
<input type="Submit" id="Padding" value="Sign up" onclick="Your_Javascript_Function()" class="btn btn-primary" />
```